# How do I find the local extrema with the first derivative test?

Tags: calculus

Determine the location of each local extremum of the function

$f(x)= -x^3 + 12x^2 - 45x - 2$

Critical values I found are $x=3$, and $x=5$

Critical points I found are $(3, -56) (5, -52)$

How do I find the local minimum/maximum?

Comment: You found them: $f(3)=-56$ is a local minimum, and $f(5)=-52$ is a local maximum.

Comment: That's weird, I entered my answer but they seem to be wrong

Comment: I don't know what form(s) you are working with, but doublecheck what is being asked. Your terminology is a bit unusual, I'd have called $3, 5$ critical points, and $-56,-52$ critical values (or local extrema).

Comment: I don't know what i'm doing really but trying to follow examples from the class

Comment: It's asking for the local minimum and to type an ordered pair, I put (3, -56) but don't know why its wrong

Comment: Ok, I'm totally confused now, the correct answer is supposed to be (-5, 48) how do they get that?

Comment: Your numbers are correct for the posted equation, as can be verified [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-x%5E3+%2B+12x%5E2+-+45x+-+2) (towards the bottom of the page).

Comment: Thanks a lot I figured what went wrong

Comment: Let me guess: $(-5,48)$ is the right answer for $f(x) = -x^3 + 12x^2 - 45x + 2$ ;-)

Comment: =P its f(x)= −x^3-12x^2−45x−2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well because theres only two local extremums, the local maximum must be at $(5, -52)$ and the local minimum is at $(3, -56)$, as the cubic function is unbounded at the ends of (-$\infty$, $\infty$).

Answer (score 0):

The local minimum or local maximum are points on your f(x) graph where there's a valley. You can find local maximum and local minimum value by using your critical points and plugging them into the second derivative. If the number f''(x)<0, then (x,f(x)) is a local max and if f''(x)>0, then it's a local min.